# Relationship between temperature and wavelength?

Tags: waves, radiation, thermal-radiation

I am investigating the relationship between wavelength and temperature.

As seen the figure below of Planks law

[image]

What is the relationship  between the lambda(max) and Temperature? or in simpler terms, you see the red dots joined together by a dotted line, what is the equation of the dotted line?

Reference:

http://www.informationphilosopher.com/solutions/scientists/planck/

Comment: You are looking for Wien's Displacement law: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wien%27s_displacement_law

Comment: @nephente You could make that an answer.

Comment: Except that it *isn't* the equation of the dotted line...

Comment: If we use the Wiens law, dont you think at temperature of 3000K, we should be getting a value less than 1 which is not the case in above figure?

Comment: @Omer Frankly, I don't understand the diagram fully. What is wavelength measured in? And "number of photons" is what? The expectation value of particle number at a given wavelength, or...

Comment: @Nephente I got the diagram from the link which I gave as a reference, the wavelength seemed to be measured in micro meters, the number of photons is the how much photons are emitted by the black body at particular temperature and velocity. I am looking for some kind of logarithmic relationship between the wavelength(frequency) and Temperature

Comment: @RobJeffries True... Seeing how the axes are labeled, I'd expect the Bose distribution plotted. But the curves clearly show Planck's law.

Comment: The website that you got the figure from is a philosophy website... there are no units on either axis so it's going to be somewhat of a pointless challenge to try and come up with formulas that relate the two "variables." The figure is just meant to give a feel for the relationship between temperature of a blackbody and intensity of photon emission at specific wavelengths (the relevant rigorous formulas are called Wien's Displacement law and Planck's law). If you would like a good conceptual understanding of the principles try https://www.e-education.psu.edu/astro801/content/l3_p5.html

Comment: Why don't the lines intersect?

Answer (score 2):

Planck's law of black-body radiation can be stated in many different ways, depending on whether one is interested in the spectral energy density per volume or per area. It can also be expressed in terms of radiation wavelength or frequency.

The energy of a photon is 
$$ \epsilon = h\nu = \frac{hc}{\lambda}$$

I will not derive Planck's law here. It can be found in any standard textbook on statistical physics or on numerous websites. Instead let us accept that the *spectral density per volume* (the unit is $\frac{\text{Energy}}{\text{Volume}\cdot\text{Wavelength}})$

$$ u(\lambda)=\frac{C}{\lambda^5} \frac{1}{\exp(D/T\lambda)-1}$$
where $C$ and $D$ are constants incorporating factors of $h,c,k_B$.

This function has a maximum depending on temperature. Taking the derivative wrt. $\lambda$ (excercise!) and equating to zero one finds an expression like
$$ \exp(D/T\lambda)(4-D/T\lambda)-4=0$$
which is rather hard to solve. But observe that the expression depends only on $x=T\lambda$ not on each quantity separately! We may thus look for the solution $x_{max}$ and substitute back to obtain $$\lambda_{max}=\frac{x_{max}}{T}$$
Whatever the numerical value of $x_{max}$ (it is $2.897\, \text{Km}$), we definitely know that $\lambda_{max}$ is inverse proportional to temperature. This is called [Wien's Displacement Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wien%27s_displacement_law).

You may now - like the diagram probably shows - be interested in the (spectral) photon density that is radiated. Easy. Simply divide the energy density by the energy per photon:
$$ n(\lambda) = \frac{u(\lambda)\lambda}{hc} $$

If you repeat the argument above to find the maximum, you'll find that the number of photons peaks at $\lambda^n_{max}$ which is also inverse to temperature.

$$\lambda^n_{max} \propto T^{-1}$$

Comment: higher temperature = more photons emitted. Your last statement cannot be correct

Comment: @pentane You're right. Wasn't my intention to claim that :-) Meant to say $\lambda_{max}$, not $n_{max}$... Corrected.